# jquery ajax sort response

Tags: ajax, jquery, sort, response

I am showing ajax response in select options as below code. I want to sort the select options in alphabetical order of values.

Please provide a solution to sort below data on values basis. 
My data is like {123:"green",124:"blue"}

```
function ajax_post(params, append_to, appent_type) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "<?= $this->getBaseUrl()?>" + "customcontroller/index/index/" + params,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {

                    if (append_to != 0) {
                        $(append_to).html('');
                        $(append_to).append('<option value="0">Select ' + appent_type + '</option>');
                        $.each(data, function (key, value) {

                            $(append_to).append('<option value="' + key + '">' + value + '</option>');
                        });
                    }
                }
            })
        }
```

Please provide a solution. I have tried to sort response in controller but when ajax loads it, it shows unsorted data.

Comment: share your options array.

Comment: @RakeshVarma my options array is like {551:"green", 552:"blue", 553:"red"}

Comment: try `asort()` in your controller.

Comment: In my controller I have below code in function  $finalModel= asort(array_combine(array_values($modelValues),array_values($modelNames)));

                $result = json_encode($finalModel);

              return $result;

Comment: But it's not working.

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like below.

```
function ajax_post(params, append_to, appent_type) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "<?= $this->getBaseUrl()?>" + "customcontroller/index/index/" + params,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            if (append_to != 0) {
                $(append_to).html('');
                $(append_to).append('<option value="0">Select ' + appent_type + '</option>');
                $.each(sortReponse(data), function (key, value) {
                    $(append_to).append('<option value="' + value.key + '">' + value.value + '</option>');
                });
            }
        }
    })
}

function sortReponse(data)
{
    var sorted = [];
    $(data).each(function(k, v) {
        for(var key in v) {
            sorted.push({key: key, value: v[key]})
        }
    });

    return sorted.sort(function(a, b){
        if (a.value < b.value) return -1;
        if (a.value > b.value) return 1;
        return 0;
    });
}
```

Try if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```
$finalModel=array_combine(array_values($modelValues),array_values($modelNames)); 
asort($finalModel);    
$result = json_encode($finalModel); 
return $result;
```

Comment: This gives error - syntax error, unexpected 'asort' (T_STRING) in line asort($finalModel);

Comment: check your code if you forget `;` in first line.

Comment: I have fixed there was some extra content but it runs as before without sorting anything.

Comment: can you post your controller code and some value of `$modelValues` and `$modelNames`

Comment: asort was not working, so I used sort. It did the work . Thanks for help.

Comment: upvote or accept the answer if its help

Comment: Hi, 
The array is sorted wit asort but in template it still shows old order.

Comment: it's known ajax response and sort issue. follow this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5020699/how-do-you-stop-chrome-and-opera-sorting-json-objects-by-index-asc

Comment: I want a solution to sort array in jquery on value basis.